# Need to be able to run a Batch file from another computer over the internet

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, remote-access, minecraft

I am running a minecraft server for a friend. And he needs to be able to start the server. I need some way to run a bat file over the internet for him. I am not really coder so. I don't know how to do this. I have been told by coder friends ssh is the way to go. I have no idea how to use ssh. Windows btw.

Comment: This really isn't a software development question. Try asking on [su]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quick Google Search, First result](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/)